# What happens when I propagate a flag in 10k-tools?

Tags: support, 10k-tools

When I use 10k tools, I see posts that have been flagged by users with insufficient rep to vote-to-close, etc.
Sometimes, I see a post flagged as "low quality" and I vote to close it. However, I wouldn't have seen that post and voted to close it if it wasn't for the flag on it. Therefore, that flag was indeed helpful, and the user who flagged it should get an increment in the number of helpful flags they've raised; but I don't see a way to mark the flag as helpful, when I vote to close the question.

Even if I were to propagate the flag (if I were to agree with it), if the flag was helpful, I get an increase in the number of helpful flags that **I've** raised, when in fact, all I did was to "move the flag to the front of the line", but not actually raise it. It feels like the user who originally raised the flag should get credit for it, but is getting "cheated" out of such credit.

So my question is "while I get credit for propagating the flag (I **am** reviewing it, after all), does the user who originally raised the flag also get credit for it?". I think they should get credit for it, and that this post should be treated as a feature request if they don't already get credit for the flag they raised (and I reviewed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For close-vote flags, as soon as anybody casts a close-vote, the flag is automatically validated.

So yes, the original flagger gets credit for it.

Although the flag is validated, I believe (not 100% sure) that it still remains in the flag-queue until the question is closed - presumably to allow other 10k users to add their close-votes.

Comment: Until the question is not closed, the flag is not automatically marked as helpful. It will be visible to other user until the question is closed.

Comment: I often see already deleted posts in the flag queue. So there is probably a delay of some kind.  (By the way chosing delete on a deleted post cast a undelete vote...).